# МинобразованиЕ

Tags: орфография

В законодательной базе увидела написание слова "МинобразованиЕ". Верно ли это? Я была уверена, что окончание "-я".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, эту базу составляли какие-то неграмотные тетки. МинобразованиЯ, конечно. А то у них получилось что-то вроде "день рождение")))))

Comment: Вообще-то это термин: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1037603
Аббревиатуры - "дело тонкое" - как восток. Иногда в них не разобраться, часто они становятся по форме приближенными к существительному определённого рода, склонения.Министерство - ср.рода,поэтому  Минобразование, роно - несклоняемое, ср.р. потому что оканчивается на  -О, так что по-разному бывает. Видимо, эта форма осталась как профессионализм.

Comment: Где еще, кроме Википедии можно увидеть это слово? Да и в той же статье в Википедии сказано, что официальное название "Минобрнауки", а вовсе не "минобразование". Так что термином это не назовешь.   Поиск на Яндексе выдал несколько строк "минобразовани**я**".

Comment: Ларf, вообще-то это не Вики, а "словари на академике". 
Надо смотреть источник

Comment: Точно. Прошу прощения, там рядом такая большая ссылка на википедию, я второпях (утром перед работой )не поняла. И все равно. В этом источнике прямо указывается на официальное сокращение: Минобрнауки.

Comment: Кстати, что конкретно за источник, я тоже что-то не пойму. А ссылку прочтите, что в ней делает  "ruwiki"? (Это я помочь разобраться  прошу)

Comment: Да я понимаю, что Вы просите разобраться.)))
Сам уже пару раз сталкивался с подобной "отсылкой".
Я думаю, что это означает использование движка вики (или его компонентов) для других ресурсов. Ну вроде как инструмент тот же, а содержание уже независимое. Сейчас это сплошь и рядом. 
Или наоборот, что ресурс доступен из вики. Я сейчас с очень слабы интернетом, как дело улучшится - попробую разобраться.  
  
Да, скорее всего это просто некий шаблон. У программистов принято давать "папкам" (фолдерам, директориям) характерные имена. В принципе назвать можно как угодно, но так искать удобнее.

Answer (score 3):

Можно по-разному подходить. Вся штука в том, что такие сокращения никак не регламентируются.
Если взять Минтранс или Минтяжмаш, Вы не потребуете родительного падежа?
Неоднократно сталкивался с "Миннаука". А почему нет? Оно вроде как название этого "Мина".

Answer (score 2):

Понимаю, что вопрос закрыт и всем всё уже понятно, но хотелось бы уточнить. Это всё-таки термин, как бы это не принималось в штыки строгими ценителями языка. Только административные термины у нас часто меняются, я даже не успеваю это замечать. В конце 90-х-начале 2-тысячных годов это было действующее сокращение, о чём говорит вышеназванный словарь для юристов и администраторов. Вот ещё документы: 
 http://www.edu.ru/db/mo/Data/d_04/pr31-1.htm
Программа Минобразования России на 2004-2007 годы «Безопасность образовательного учреждения»:"Ответственные за исполнение программы:  Минобразование России, с участием МЧС России, Госстроя России и т.д.

http://gia.edu.ru/ru/main/legal-documents/index.php?id_4=17855
Приказ Минобразования России от 03.12.1999 №1075 «Об утверждении Положения о государственной (итоговой) аттестации выпускников IX и XI 
2.6. Сроки проведения письменных экзаменов в IX классах общеобразовательных учреждений устанавливает государственный орган управления образованием субъекта Российской Федерации, на территории которого расположены эти учреждения, в XI (XII) классах — Минобразование России.

Это неофициальное сокращение, официальное -Минобрнауки, сейчас действует другое НЕОФИЦИАЛЬНОЕ сокращение - Минобразования.

Но это ни в коем случае не говорит о том, что раньше чиновники были " какие-то неграмотные тетки", это говорит о том, что язык совершенствуется. Давайте будем корректными...

Comment: Позволю себе реплику. по поводу замечания:"Это всё-таки термин..." В последнее время бюрократическая  практика породила множество языковых монстров, претендующих на статус узаконенных конструктов.. Это - давний и, увы, все набирающий силу деструктивный фактор, приводящий к искажению языка, к многочисленным коммуникативным затруднениям. Об этом прекрасно писали Селищев (Язык революционной эпохи") и Чуковский ("Живой как жизнь").  Унять эту беззаконную вакханалию можно не иначе как с помощью учреждения "Лингвистической полиции", то есть родственными для самой бюрократии методами (шутка). :)

Comment: Иногда да, иногда нет, о каждом случае надо говорить отдельно, но я всё-таки придерживаюсь мнения, что русский язык сам за себя постоит, всё нездоровое в конце концов исчезнет, а удержится в языке то, что удобно для его носителей. К пуристам я не отношусь, я за развитие.

Answer (score 0):

А если сравнить: место жительства - словосочетание, местожительство - термин. Чтобы наименование функционировало как слово, ему нужен статус (род,  спряжение, число) только в этом случае оно может вступать в грамматические связи. Если даже "минообразование" не является официальным названием, оно все равно должно прописаться в языке, а для этого больше походить окончание Е, например: Минобразование (И.п.) - указ Минобразования (Р.п.)- принят Минобразованием (Т.п.)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
День рождения не может прописаться, ему мягкий знак мешает.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2. 
По поводу Минтранса: Р.п. этому слову очень даже к лицу, например:"Как Вы оцениваете работу, проводимую должностными лицами Минтранса России?"

Вообще, подобные слова (каждый по-своему) стараются вписаться в словоизменительную систему языка, в частности Минтранс склоняется как существительное м.р. с нулевым окончанием. Поэтому вариант   "Минобразования" в И.п. выглядит, мягко говоря, странно.

Comment: Почему бы тогда не прописаться и слову "деньрожденье" как наименованию праздника? Чем оно хуже слова "минобразование"? А уж употребляется точно чаще!