# Чем обусловлено употребление именительного падежа вместо родительного в аббревиатуре "Минобразование"?

Tags: грамматика, аббревиатуры

Сокращенное название Министерства образования и науки - "МИНОБРАЗОВАНИЕ"- фиксируется в ряде документов ведомства, т.е. широко тиражируется и, волей или неволей, входит в практику повседневного употребления. Вместе с тем возникает вопрос по поводу  грамматического оформления данной аббревиатуры: насколько оно соответствует нормам русского языка? Вопрос это - нетривиален и касается, на мой взгляд, существенных тенденций в развитии СРЛЯ. Возможно, данное написание является следствием аналитических тенденций, развивающихся в русском языке под влиянием английского языка ("в городе Ливны"). Русский язык относится к числу синтетических, т.е. грамматические значения выражаются, преимущественно, через изменение словоформ (склонение, спряжение и пр.). В английском языке грамматические значения выражаются, в основном, на синтаксическом уровне, через построение предложения; существительные не склоняются.

Следует также заметить, что отказ от склонения в пусть не совсем официальном, но повсеместно распространенном сокращенном названии авторитетного государственного учреждения (данное сокращение, в норме, относится к типу:"аббревиатуры из сочетания начальной части слова с формой косвенного падежа"),  на мой взгляд, может сыграть роль своеобразного образца,  эталона для ненормативного терминотворчества по "аналитическому типу" и в других ведомствах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26988/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%95

Comment: На бланках? Вообще-то офицальное сокращение - Минобрнауки...

Comment: То, что я не один обратил на это внимание, доказывает распространенность документов с данным сокращением. Я распространил тело вопроса, переместив его в системную языковую плоскость.

Comment: Скорее, тут действует тенденция подстроить сокращение под законы русского языка. Интересные рассуждения можно найти по ссылке (см. выше)

Comment: Перешел по ссылке. Все внимательно прочитал. Спасибо. В связи с чиновничьим языком и бюрократическим терминотворчеством можно процитировать А.П.Чехова: “Какая гадость чиновничий язык. «Исходя из положения», «с одной стороны...», «с другой стороны», и все это без всякой надобности. «Тем не менее», «по мере того» чиновники сочинили. Я читаю и отплевываюсь... Неясно, холодно и неизящно: пишет, сукин сын, точно холодный в гробу лежит»

Answer (score 1):

Мѝнобразова́ния

Существительное, неодушевлённое, средний род, **несклоняемое** (тип склонения 0 по классификации А. А. Зализняка).

В Минобразования думают запретить телефоны на уроке. Приказ по Минобразования.

Встречаются, конечно, ошибки, но это не практика повседневного употребления. Именительный падеж никто не нормирует.

Comment: Эта форма (Минобразование) была зафиксирована на официальных письмах. На стандартном бланке. В реквизите "Адресант". Видел своими глазами.

Comment: В законодательной базе данная форма тоже отражена . Этот момент уже обсуждался на нашем сайте(см. первый комментарий к моему вопросу). Тогда все уважаемые члены лингвистического сообщества пришли к выводу, что, мол, это, уже термин, и ничего тут не поделаешь. Таковы, мол,законы развития языка. Поэтому я вновь поставил вопрос. И Ваша ссылка весьма кстати.